# What are the all primes $p$ so that $-1/2$ has square roots in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

**Square root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$:**

Assume $p$ is an odd prime. Consider a p-adic unit $\alpha=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\cdots \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

The question is- $\text{which such $\alpha$ has square root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$}$ ?

It turns out that-

$\alpha$ has square root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff $a_0$ is  quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Now for $p \neq 2$, $-\frac{1}{2}$ is a $p$-adic unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Let us check whether $-1/2$ has a square root in $\mathbb{Q}_3$. For that,
$$ -1/2=\frac{1}{1-3}={\color{blue}{1}}+3+3^2+\cdots \ \text{and} \ {\color{blue}{1}}\equiv 2^2 \ \text{mod}\ 3. $$
Thus $-1/2$ has a sqaure root in $\mathbb{Q}_3$.

Is it equivalent to say that $+1/2$ also has square root in $\mathbb{Q}_3$  ?

Similarly, I have checked that $-1/2$ has square roots in $\mathbb{Q}_{11}$, $\mathbb{Q}_{17}$, $\mathbb{Q}_{19}, \cdots $

> $(1)$ What are the all primes $p$ so that $-1/2$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ?

> $(2)$ what about the general formula so that $\pm \frac{m}{n}$ has square roots in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $ m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: If $x$ is a unit, then $a$ is a square if and only if $a\cdot x^2$ is a square. What is a natural candidate for $x$ in your question?

Comment: The number $-1/2$ has a square root in a field if and only if its reciprocal $-2$ has. For odd primes $p$ this happens in $\Bbb{Q}_p$  if and only if $-2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. The usual business with Hensel's lemma.

Comment: @DanielFischer, natural candidate means ? In question $(1)$ I asked what are the all primes $p$ so that $-1/2$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ? I found that if $p \equiv 1, \ 3$ (mod $8$), then $-1/2$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Is that all primes ?

Comment: Yes, $\bigl(\frac{-2}{p}\bigr) = 1 \iff p \equiv 1,3 \pmod{8}$. And $-\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2^2 = -2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, what are the all $p$, so that $-2$ is quadratic residue modulo $p$ ?

Comment: @DanielFischer, what about $+1/2$ ? I think it is not equivalent to the case $-1/2$ ?

Comment: $1/2$ has a square root iff $2$ has. $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, iff $p\equiv1,7\pmod8$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Final question how do we deal the cases when the numerator is not $1$ ? i.e., How to deal with $\frac{m}{n}$ ? When does it has square root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$? see question (2)

Comment: $m/n$ is a square if and only if $(m/n)n^2=mn$ is a square. Numerator, denominator, makes no difference.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Thank you very much